# Retrieving a specific line of text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<li class="b-list__box-list-item b-list__box-list-item_type_block">
      <i class="b-list__box-item-title b-list__box-item-title_type_width">
        Height:
      </i>
      6' 2"
</li>
```

For the above, I only want to retrieve 6'2" and ignore "height."  my code

```
stat_one = stat_table_one.find_all("li", {"class": "b-list__box-list-item b-list__box-list-item_type_block"})

for li in stat_one:
    print li.get_text()
```

This code pulls "Height" and 6'2".  Is there a way to just get 6'2"?

Comment: very odd structure...i would just check if the first char is a number. Ideally, I would not do it this way at all.

Comment: I'd probably just find i element, get text of that and used str.replace to delete it from the whole li.get text

Comment: @Casper Wylie. What is odd about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: h = """<li class="b-list__box-list-item b-list__box-list-item_type_block">
   ...:       <i class="b-list__box-item-title b-list__box-item-title_type_width">
   ...:         Height:
   ...:       </i>
   ...:       6' 2"
   ...: </li>
   ...: """    
In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(h,"html.parser")

In [4]: "".join(soup.find("li").find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip()

Out[4]: u'6\' 2"'
```

You dont want the child text so don't look recursively.

Comment: Sorry, how would I go about doing it for another li sibling with similar structure but different text -- Weight:   and 145lbs?  I only want the 145lbs.